# Reset a page to site/feature definition programmatically?

Tags: 2007, ghosting

I'm looking for a way to programmatically reset a page to that page's site/feature definition, without using SharePoint Designer.  There must be some sort of API that can do this, but my Googling around is coming up empty...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SPFile.RevertContentStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.revertcontentstream.aspx) is what you're looking for. Remember this will only work when the file really does have an uncustomized version on the file system though.